# Mod rewrite remove trailing slash but keep on directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So far my `.htaccess` is like this:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 
  <FilesMatch "\.(htm|php|js|css|htc|png|gif|jpe?g|ico|xml|csv|txt|swf|flv|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf|gz)$">
    RewriteEngine Off
  </FilesMatch>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .*\.html$ index.php [L]
```

I would like to have url with trailing slash redirected to the one without. But the slash for directories should be kept.

Any help would be very appreciated!

UPDATE: 
after some more Google research i assembled some working solution for me. Both rewriting for removing trailing slash and redirect for www are working.

```
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rudolfapotheke.de$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: sorry for my bad english....

Answer (score 1):

First, I would change your `FilesMatch` to a `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(?:htm|php|js|css|htc|png|gif|jpe?g|ico|xml|csv|txt|swf|flv|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf|gz)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

and simplify the pattern for the next `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.html$ index.php [L]
```

or put the two rules together and test just for

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

and finally the rule for removing the trailing slash

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thx for this inspiring answer. havn´t tested it so far because after some hours of trying i found a working solution. the language of the htacess is still a big miracle for me so im not sure if this makes it best solution: `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rudolfapotheke.de$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301] `

Comment: @Arwed From a quick glance, this looks fine. And if it works for you, this is the best answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To redirect those with trailing slash, you need to check if the path is a directory with a `RewriteCond` and then include a `RewriteRule` if the filename matchs `/$`

So it would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Sorry doesnt work for me. Always one of the desired features doesnt work. As it is redirect from non www to www does work. If i add something to remove the slash, the www redirect stopps.